# Is it possible to use mongoose function find() on different models at the same time?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I'm using expressJS and my question is about one of my controller; I'm looking into 3 different models if their respective attribut 'kanji' are matching the kanji passed as parameter in the URL. To do so, i'm calling the function find() on my 3 models, and stock all the results in a variable 'result' to return it :

```
const Word = require('../models/wordModel');
const Verb = require('../models/verbModel');
const Adj = require('../models/adjectiveModel');

exports.getWordsByKanji = (req, res, next) => {

let result = [];

Word.find({kanji: {"$regex": req.params.kanji, "$options": "i"}})
    .then(word => {
        result = word;

        Verb.find({kanji: {"$regex": req.params.kanji, "$options": "i"}})
            .then(verb => {
                
                for(let i = 0; i < verb.length; i++) {
                    result.push(verb[i])
                }
                
                Adj.find({kanji: {"$regex": req.params.kanji, "$options": "i"}})
                    .then(adj => {
                        
                        for(let i = 0; i < adj.length; i++) {
                            result.push(adj[i])
                        }
                        
                        res.status(200).json(result)
                    })
            })
    })
    .catch((error) => res.status(500).json({ 'Error': error }));
}
```

This is working well, but i was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do it. This function looks quite heavy with a lot of data, and it's not really DRY. Cheers !

Comment: assuming that the input of one call doesn't depend on the one before, [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) might be what you need?

at the moment you're doing the three operations in sequence - with promise.all you could do them concurrently and save a lot of time.

Comment: Just looked for it, and that is exactly what I needed !! Thank you so much